# set specific bone as child of object

Tags: constraints, inverse-kinematics

The pencil in picture follows a path, and the hand bones connected with IK,
I want the last smallest bone to follow the pencil location.

when I add constrain in edit or pose mode, it parents the entire armature, so the entire arm follows.

How to parent only the last bone while other two follow IK?

Edit: the solution is in the IK target - an "empty" named handGrip, parented to pencil.

[image]

Comment: Are you parenting the IK-Handle to the pencil? Or are you making it follow the pencil with a constraint?

Comment: I want the IK-Handle to follow the pencil.
The pencil is moving in its path and the hand should follow.

Comment: If you want, upload your file here 
https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/
and I'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the IK-Handle to stay in the same position as the pencil, simply use a Bone Constraint on the IK-Handle. Select the IK-Handle in Pose Mode and add the **Copy Location Constraint** from the **Bone Constraint Menu** (not the regular Object Constraints, see screenshot). **Choose the pencil as a target**, the bone will then follow the pencils origin.

[image: Bone Following Object with Copy Location Constraint]

If that origin is not where you would like, simply parent an Empty to the pencil in the place you want the hand to grip it and target the Bone Constraint to that Empty.

Comment: Do you mean the Head of the Upper Arm bone with "first" bone?

Comment: You need to add it to your question.

Comment: Hi many thanks for your answer! I recreate all bones and now it functions well.